# SAQL Query in CRM Analytics

Tags: saql, crm-analytics

I'm trying to filter the Case object on 'ClosedDate'. For instance, I want to get all the Cases that were closed yesterday. My current query uses relative string literals as such:

```
q = load "CS_Cases";
q = filter q by date('ClosedDate_Year', 'ClosedDate_Month', 'ClosedDate_Day') in ["1 day ago".."1 day ago"];
q = group q by all;
q = foreach q generate unique(q.'CaseNumber') as 'A';
q = limit q 2000;
```

My problem is that I'm trying to work around TimeZone constraints, since Salesforce uses GMT and I need to filter based on GMT -6hrs. I've tried to modify the string literal on line 2 as such:

```
q = filter q by date('ClosedDate_Year', 'ClosedDate_Month', 'ClosedDate_Day') in ["1 day ago - 6h".."1 day ago - 6h"];
```

This is not a valid string literal.

I've also tried creating variables and using them in a comparator, something along the idea of below, but I can't find any documentation on creating/using variables in SAQL:

```
startDateTime = <yesterday at midnight in epoch_seconds here> 
endDateTime = <yesterday at 23:59:59 in epoch_seconds here>
q = filter q by 'ClosedDate' >= startDateTime and 'ClosedDate' <= endDateTime;
```

Any help appreciated.